# When hovering over an image in Chrome, the image disappears

Tags: html, css

I cannot get an image's opacity to work in Chrome.  The image disappears as soon as I hover over the image.  I have searched the internet, and cannot find anything that works.  The opacity works with an `<input>` tag, but wont with an `<img>` tag.  I have already tried `position: relative;` It works perfectly fine in all other browsers...http://jsfiddle.net/nx2bcpdu/  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to add the attr(title)?

Comment: I used it for a tooltip...I stripped most of the code for the jsfiddle example for simplicity.  I got my answer from jmore009, thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're calling `content: attr(title);` which is breaking the image on hover:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nx2bcpdu/1/)

Comment: works perfect....sucks that I spent a good hour and a half on something so simple.  Thanks, I appreciate it.